# Passing location to different view with segue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

very very new to iOS programming, so I appreciate any help with this.
All I actually want to do is pass the variable of my current coordinates to a different view when a button is pressed. I can't work out how to do this using my current work - I'm getting in a total muddle. My project is essentially made from lots of chunks of code from various sources. I'll share with you the parts that I think are relevant, and hopefully somebody can at least point me in the right direction!

This is from my MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

if (currentPosition == nil) {

    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(newLocation.coordinate);

    double pointsPerMeter = MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude(newLocation.coordinate.latitude);


    double visibleDistance = pointsPerMeter * 500.0;

    MKMapRect rect = MKMapRectMake(
                                   point.x - visibleDistance, point.y - visibleDistance,
                                   visibleDistance * 2, visibleDistance * 2);
           [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:rect animated:YES];



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://url.url/json.json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


    NSError *error;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {

    }


    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         
    NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation;                        


    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array)
    {


        location.latitude = [dictionary[@"lat"] doubleValue];
        location.longitude = [dictionary[@"lon"] doubleValue];


        newAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

        newAnnotation.coordinate = location;



        HUWMapAnnotation *annotation = [[HUWMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newAnnotation.coordinate];
        annotation.messagetitle = dictionary[@"name"];
        annotation.email = dictionary[@"message"];
        annotation.username = dictionary[@"user"];

        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

        [newAnnotations addObject:newAnnotation];

    }




}
currentPosition = newLocation;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad { [super viewDidLoad];

// Check if the user has enabled location services.
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    // Create a location manager.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // Set ourselves as it's delegate so that we get notified of position updates.
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    // Set the desired accuracy.
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    // Start tracking.
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
}
```

Like I said, I've trimmed this down substantially to the bits I think are relevant. Let me know if I have missed something essential. I've got my storyboard set up with a button ready to go, and a segue with its identifier.

I assume that I should be using `prepareForSegue` - but my issue is that I quite simply don't know how to get my coordinates into that situation.

I hope somebody will be able to help me (and I apologise for the large amount of copy-pasted code!)

Comment: Side note: Instead of calculating MKMapPoints per meter, it's much easier to use the [MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209-CH2-SW5) and do setRegion instead of setVisibleRect.

Comment: I will look into implementing that, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass objects between view controllers using segues, do something like the following:

1) create a segue between the source and destination view controllers in IB, give it an identifier `@"MySegue"`.

2) let's say the destination vc needs a string to run:

```
// DestinationVC.h
@interface DestinationVC : UIViewController
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@end
```

3) the source vc initiates a segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
```

4) the source vc prepares by initializing the property on the destination vc:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        DestinationVC *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.string = // some object that the source vc has.  this could be your CLLocationCoordinate2D
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Just for clarification: In point [3], where should I put this line exactly?

Comment: Line 3 shouldn't be necessary if you're doing the segues directly in the storyboard. That code would be useful if you want to perform the segue from a non-storyboard event. I think @danh placed it there just to illustrate.

Comment: @Can is correct in that IB lets you attach the starting end of segues to things like buttons and table cells.  Those are performed when the user presses the button or selects the cell etc, and you wouldn't need step 3.  You can also draw the segue from one view controller to another and then initiate them in code as I suggest in step 3.  If you do it this way, you will call perform segue at whenever you want the segue to happen, for example, once you've received location data.